# WPF Control Disposal

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dispose

In WinForms, for all controls there is the `.OnDisposed` override, the `Disposed` event, and the `IsDisposed` property.

WPF seems to have no equivalent.

How can I listen for the disposal of a `UserControl` in a WPF application?

To be more clear; I need to know when the control is removed. The reason being that for some controls I want to keep a static reference to the control for easier access to it, and when the control is no longer in scope, I need to set that reference to null.

To be even more clear :

```
public class Foo : UserControl{
    private static Foo _Instance;
    //For ease of access. I do not want to have to call Control.Control.Control.Control.FooVar.DoSomething() when I can call Foo.Instance.DoSomething()
    public static Foo Instance { get { return Foo._Instance ?? new Foo() } }

    public Foo(){
        this.InitializeComponents();
        /*Other Initialization Stuff*/
        Foo._Instance = this; /*<---- This needs to be set to null when Foo is closed/disposed/removed/out of scope etc.*/
    }        
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure WPF objects are not like GDI+ objects, they don't use unmanaged resources and therefore didn't need to implement IDisposable. Do you want to know about "Disposal" in the sense of garbage collection and releasing resources, or you just want to know when its removed?

Comment: @RonBeyer : When it is removed.

Comment: But if there is no Foo there is no private static Foo _Instance;.  Why do you need to set that to null?   If it is null then why would you create a new Foo?

Comment: @Blam You evidently missed where, in the constructor, I set Foo._Instance = this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to statically reference objects, but without keeping them in-memory, you could always elect for a [`WeakReference<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly static WeakReference<MyControl> _instance
        = new WeakReference<T>(null);

    public static MyControl Instance
    {
        get
        {
            UserControl result;
            if(!_instance.TryGetTarget(out result))
                _instance.SetTarget(result = new MyControl());

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This, however, introduces the possibility that, depending on the whims of the GC, you may get the *same* control after quickly closing and refreshing a page. In such case, you should make sure the `Unloaded` event triggers a nullification of the instance

```
// Ensure the instance is cleared when unloading
public void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    _instance.SetTarget(null);
}
```

and then in your XAML...

```
<UserControl ...
             Unloaded="OnUnloaded">
```

Comment: One thing - Isn't the static WeakReference null by default? Wouldn't calling the .TryGetTarget function or the .SetTarget method throw a null reference exception?